# Using cbind causes wrong interpretation of numeric variable

Tags: r

When I build the following data.frame:

```
cntrydata<-as.data.frame(cbind(c('BE', 'BG', 'CH', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DK', 'EE', 
             'ES', 'FI', 'FR', 'GB', 'GR', 'HR', 'HU', 'IE', 
             'IL', 'LT', 'NL', 'NO', 'PL', 'PT', 'RU', 'SE', 
             'SI', 'SK', 'UA'),c('C', 'P', 'C', 'P', 'P', 'C', 
             'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'C',
             'P', 'P', 'C', 'C', 'P', 'C', 'P', 'C', 'P', 'P', 'P'),
              c(7.1, 3.6, 8.7, 6.3, 4.6, 7.9, 9.3, 6.5, 
                6.1, 9.1, 6.8, 7.6, 3.5, 4.1, 4.7, 8, 6.1, 5, 8.8,
                8.6, 5.3, 6, 2.1, 9.2, 6.4, 4.3, 2.4)))
colnames(cntrydata)<-c('cntry','mode','CPI')
```

The CPI variable is of the `class(factor)`, while I need it to be numeric to make the following function to work:

```
boxplot(CPI~mode, data=cntrydata)
```

I tried the following:

```
as.numeric(levels(cntrydata$CPI))[cntrydata$CPI]
```

As adviced on [How to convert a factor to an integer\numeric without a loss of information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-an-integer-numeric-without-a-loss-of-information)

But it is still of the class factor. Any ideas how to reach my goal?

Also, but less importantly, I was looking how to include the `colnames` argument in the data construction command (instead of afterwards, as I did eventually). But couldn't find how and where to put it?

Comment: `class(as.numeric(levels(cntrydata$CPI))[cntrydata$CPI])` returns `numeric`

Comment: `cbind` here is trying to give you everything of the same kind, which isn't what you want - and you don't need it here anyway.  Do: `cntrydata<-data.frame(cntry=c('BE', 'BG', 'CH', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DK', 'EE',
'ES', 'FI', 'FR', 'GB', 'GR', 'HR', 'HU', 'IE',
'IL', 'LT', 'NL', 'NO', 'PL', 'PT', 'RU', 'SE'),mode=c('C', 'P', 'C', 'P', 'P', 'C',
'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'C',
'P', 'P', 'C', 'C', 'P', 'C', 'P', 'C'),
CPI=c(7.1, 3.6, 8.7, 6.3, 4.6, 7.9, 9.3, 6.5,
6.1, 9.1, 6.8, 7.6, 3.5, 4.1, 4.7, 8, 6.1, 5, 8.8,
8.6, 5.3, 6, 2.1, 9.2))` etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following would do the conversion:

```
cntrydata$CPI <- as.numeric(as.character(cntrydata$CPI))
```

If you were to construct the data frame as follows, you wouldn't have the issue and you'd also get the column names:

```
> cntrydata <- data.frame(cntry=c('BE', 'BG', 'CH', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DK', 'EE', 
+              'ES', 'FI', 'FR', 'GB', 'GR', 'HR', 'HU', 'IE', 
+              'IL', 'LT', 'NL', 'NO', 'PL', 'PT', 'RU', 'SE', 
+              'SI', 'SK', 'UA'), mode=c('C', 'P', 'C', 'P', 'P', 'C', 
+              'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'C',
+              'P', 'P', 'C', 'C', 'P', 'C', 'P', 'C', 'P', 'P', 'P'),
+               CPI=c(7.1, 3.6, 8.7, 6.3, 4.6, 7.9, 9.3, 6.5, 
+                 6.1, 9.1, 6.8, 7.6, 3.5, 4.1, 4.7, 8, 6.1, 5, 8.8,
+                 8.6, 5.3, 6, 2.1, 9.2, 6.4, 4.3, 2.4))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your main problem is the way you're creating the `data.frame`. Do not use `cbind` and `as.data.frame`. Try this:

```
cntrydata <- data.frame( cntry = c('BE', 'BG', 'CH', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DK', 'EE', 
         'ES', 'FI', 'FR', 'GB', 'GR', 'HR', 'HU', 'IE', 
         'IL', 'LT', 'NL', 'NO', 'PL', 'PT', 'RU', 'SE', 
         'SI', 'SK', 'UA'), mode = c('C', 'P', 'C', 'P', 'P', 'C', 
         'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'C',
         'P', 'P', 'C', 'C', 'P', 'C', 'P', 'C', 'P', 'P', 'P'),
          CPI = c(7.1, 3.6, 8.7, 6.3, 4.6, 7.9, 9.3, 6.5, 
            6.1, 9.1, 6.8, 7.6, 3.5, 4.1, 4.7, 8, 6.1, 5, 8.8,
            8.6, 5.3, 6, 2.1, 9.2, 6.4, 4.3, 2.4))

sapply(cntrydata, class)
#     cntry      mode       CPI 
#  "factor"  "factor" "numeric"
```

This is because, when you use `cbind`, at least one argument of to it must be a `data.frame` for your data to be a `data.frame`. If not, the result will be a `matrix`. And in a `matrix`, all data should be of the same class. And since one or more columns of your data are `character` type, the numeric column is also coerced to `character` data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `as.character()`  before `as.numeric`

The reason for this is that `factor`s are in reality integers with key-value label.
If you use simply `as.numeric(someFactor)` you are gettting the equivalent of the key.
You want the equivalent of the value, which you can get via `as.character`.
But then you want your final result to be numeric, hence you wrap it all together:

```
 as.numeric(as.character(someFactor))
```

Compare:

```
 > as.numeric(cntrydata$CPI)
  [1] 17  4 22 13  7 19 26 15 12 24 16 18  3  5  8 20 12  9 23 21 10 11  1 25 14  6  2

 > as.numeric(as.character(cntrydata$CPI))
  [1] 7.1 3.6 8.7 6.3 4.6 7.9 9.3 6.5 6.1 9.1 6.8 7.6 3.5 4.1 4.7 8.0 6.1 5.0 8.8 8.6
 [21] 5.3 6.0 2.1 9.2 6.4 4.3 2.4
```